# Throughput in Apache storm

Tags: apache-storm

I want to know exactly throughput in apache Storm. Is it the number of tuples processed/Total time?

If so what is the total number of tuples emitted? I am not getting exact significance of total tuples emitted/Time. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the execute count of the sink bolts (the end ones in your topology that don't connect to any other bolts). This is the throughput and is reported for the last 10 mins, 3 hrs, 1 day and all time. Dividing the values by the time period in seconds will give you the throughput in tuples per second.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your answer but what about the total number of Acked in topology stats for 10 mins, 3 hrs 1 day.... Isn't it gives us the total number of tuples acked after processing through the topology so total number of processed tuples?

Comment: If you have acking enabled then the ack-count of the spouts will show you the number of spout messages successfully processed.

Comment: Yeah That's true but I enabled acking for all bolts too and anyways spout messages are the input to the topology, so number of spout messages successfully processed are the total number of tuples completely processed through the topology. That's what I am thinking. Please correct me if I am wrong.